# Refactoring old javascript, ideas

Tags: javascript

I got now some old project with a lot of javascript I need to refactor.

A lot of the code is just inline in the html or invoking from there and the main js file is in the head of the page. Because of that the rendering time of the page is pretty low. I wanted to move all the main code before ending body tag and also all the inline functions. Thats how it looked the main file: the functions in the main file are just packed in the one object

```
var namespace = {

category1: {

func1: function(attr){

}

}

etc

}
```

and calling from code inline like namespace.category.func(dynamicattr)

I wanted to remove all this inline code and make some small library to call all the functions from main namespaces. I wanted to use data-attr to store the dynamic attributes. My library will just looked all the data-attr and invoked necessary functions from the main namespaces.

What do you think about this solution? Maybe its not the prettiest solution but we will remove all the blocking code is now in that page.

Comment: Have you tried posting this at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @PakkuDon Code Review requires full working code...

Comment: So implement it and see how it works. It is personal opinion if it is a good or bad solution.

Comment: Yes, the thing is Im just working on the existing code... Most important thing is to remove js that blocking rendering process. If I'll implement solution then it will be to late :P so before starting it will be to get some feedback, ideas, how to make it right not the full solution. Afterwards I can put my code there of course.